# mapping a Parameter to a specific payload with generics in TS

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to map a payload to a specific parameter

```js
type ParameterPayload = {
  a: { payloadA: string };
  b: { payloadB: string };
  c: { payloadC: string };
};

type Parameter = keyof ParameterPayload;
```

I then declare a function that takes a parameter and its payload as arguments:

```js
const setParameter = <P extends Parameter>(parameter: P, payload: ParameterPayload[P]) => {
  console.log({ parameter, payload });
};
```

If I try to use `setParameter` directly, it acts as I expected:

```js
setParameter('a', { payloadA: 'foo' }); // OK
setParameter('b', { payloadA: 'foo' }); // Error
```

but if I wrap `setParameter`, I don't have any TS error:

```js
const run = (parameter: Parameter) => {
  return setParameter(parameter, { payloadB: 'bar' }); // No Error
};
```

Does anyone have an explanation? And an idea how to raise an error here and force me to check the value of parameter before calling `setParameter` so that I can use the proper payload ?

Regards,
Julien

Comment: If you pass a `Parameter`, then you're allowing all types of payloads. What kind of error do you want anyways? You can create an intersection instead of a union to emit an error where the payload is as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WKPJzw), or maybe you want to disallow calling the function with unions entirely, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wj0d7m)...

Comment: When `P` is the full `Parameter` union, then `ParameterPayload[P]` is also the full union of payload types, so generic functions like that are technically unsafe, although this issue doesn't come up often enough for the language to do much about it.  If your use case really wants to prevent bad calls, you can make `setParameter` take a union of rest args [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/WJVKDW).  Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Because in the second case, you are expecting `P:Parameter` and TS evaluates that as `ParameterPayload["a" | "b" | "c"]`, which gives you the possibility to enter all payloads. To fix it, simply add the generic argument.

```
const run = <P extends Parameter>(parameter: P) => {
  return setParameter<P>(parameter, { payloadB: 'bar' }); // Error
};
```